# Writing to read-only files

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a program (c#.net 2.0)that looks through all ini files within a given directory, and attempts to replace some string patterns if found. Some of these .ini files are read-only, and there is a vast amount of them.

Any suggestions on how best to handle this? It is going to be used in a win2k, win2k3 32bit environment with up to .net 2.0 installed.

Comment: Have you considered removing the read-only bit while you modify the files?

Comment: If the files are marked as read-only by the OS, then you cannot write to then without changing that attribute.

Comment: it seems perhaps I could use the dos command "attr -r c:\directory\*.ini", how would I implement that in c# code?

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the readonly attribute (you can only do this if you have the correct permissions):

```
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
myFile.IsReadOnly = false;
```

The file is now writable - see the documentation on the [`IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly.aspx) property.

Answer (score 4):

Just clear the ReadOnly attribute

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

but first check if it's there

```
bool isReadOnly = (File.GetAttributes(FilePath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Good to have seen this method as well.